# What is the Approx query time for Realm for Stationery Objects?

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm to save the Stationery Objects in Android which will never change throughout the app lifecycle.

I have two fields, code(6 digits) and name(4 digits). And the size of Realm is around 200 objects.

I also, have a recycler view where I showing the username corresponding to the code like this.

```
Data Data = realm.where(Data.class).equalTo("code", code).findFirst();
```

So, I was wondering the query time the realm would take if the user fling scroll or scroll fast enough to make the realm query time long.is it the safe practice to use Realm this way ? or is there any other alternative ?

Comment: I think your question is not about the query time, but if it is a good and safe practice to use that line. Could you update the question please?

Comment: No. I want to know the computation it takes to query a single "code" in the Realm db in my case. And what if in recycler view, the user scroll that the query time increases.

Comment: Well, certainly you could trace or profile this method call? I don't see how the first part is realm-specific.

Comment: I mean I could use SharedPreferences for my purpose but instead, I want to use Realm because it offers more flexibility. I am also concerned about the time single or multiple queries to the Realm DB would take as compared to the SharedPreferences, I am pretty sure SharedPreferences take less time but keeping in mind the flexibility Realm provides I was curious about the time Realm takes.

Comment: @CarstenHagemann any insights?

Comment: Like I previously commented, just try to trace/profile the methods. You will find enough with those keywords on google/SO.